# Kendo MVC Fluent filterable option

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

how can I exclude particular coloumns from beeing filterable in the kendo grid?

```
.Navigatable()
          .Scrollable(a => a.Height("auto"))
          .Filterable(f => { f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row);
                               f.Extra(false);

          })
```

I do not find anythign for the server side (fluent).

Comment: ..and off-topic: how can I use line breaks? my greetings get always lost even with 2 spaces at the end...

Answer (score 0):

..okay I just figured it out by myself in the meantime:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.value).Filterable(**true/false**);
```

is what I was looking for.
But now I am stuck at another point: My custom filter options do not work.
I got just same result as default:

```
.Filterable(f =>  f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row)
                            .Extra(false)
                            .Operators(operators => operators
                                .ForDate(date => date.Clear()
                                    .IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Ab")
                                    .IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Bis")
                                )
                                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                    .Contains("Beinhaltet")
                                )
                             )  
         )
```

Any idea on that?